# I am able to to get the attr of populated element but I cannot set the attribute

Tags: jquery, forms, attributes

I have a row that is cloned by click event from a table which is also cloned. I am not sure if that is the reason I cannot set the attribute name but just to be cleared it's been cloned the 2nd time.

```
var ipCount = 2;
$("#input_form").on("click", "#add_input_param", function() {
    $('#input_param tr').eq(1).clone().find('input').val('').end()
            .appendTo('#input_param > thead').trigger('creat')
            .find('*[name]')
            .each(function() {
       //alert(i);
       alert( $(this).attr('name'));
        $(this).setAttribute = ('name', 'new_name');
            });
    ipCount++;
});
```

Now that my question is:
1. Why is it that I can get the attribute but not setting it.
2. I would like my .each(function(){}) only loop through the last row that was created by this click event. (not all of them like it is showing right now)

Any help I'd appriciate it. Thanks in advanced.

This is my HTML block:

```
    <h4>
                        3.3.5 Input Parameters
                    </h4>
                    <table id="input_param" >
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Parameter</th>
                                <th>Data Type</th>
                                <th>Required</th>
                                <th>Brief description</th>
                                <th>Location in Request</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="text" name=":ops1/6/1/1_param" /></td>
                                <td><input type="text" name=":ops1/6/1/1_type" /></td>
                                <td>
                                    <select id="required" name=":ops1/6/1/1_required">
                                        <option value="Mandatory" >Mandatory</option>
                                        <option value="Optional" >Optional</option>
                                        <option value="Conditional" >Conditional</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                                <td><textarea name=":ops1/6/1/1_desc"></textarea></td>
                                <td>
                                    <select name=":ops1/6/1/1_location">
                                        <option value="Header" >Header</option>
                                        <option value="Body" >Body</option>
                                        <option value="Query_param" >Query Parameter</option>
                                        <option value="Resource_uri" >Resource URI</option>
                                    </select>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>     
                    <input type="button" id="add_input_param" value="+ Add Input Parameter" data-inline="true" /><br />
```

Answer (score 2):

Code isn't formatted properly currently.

This

```
 $('#input_param tr').eq(1).clone().find('input').val('').end()
        .appendTo('#input_param > thead').trigger('creat')
        .find('*[name]')
        .each(function() {
   //This is working.
   alert( $(this).attr('name'));
   //This is not working.
   $(this).attr("name", "new_name"
        });
```

should be

```
 $('#input_param tr').eq(1).clone().find('input').val('').end()
        .appendTo('#input_param > thead').trigger('creat')
        .find('*[name]')
        .each(function() {
   //This is working.
   alert( $(this).attr('name'));
   //This is not working.
   $(this).attr("name", "new_name"); //<-- added );
        });
```

Comment: It must have been the copy and paste... I just changed my original question. This is not working... Thanks for pointing out the mistake though.